# Offset the text wrap of a textarea so text isn't obscured by icon

Tags: html, css, textarea, word-wrap

I'm working on a chat application in HTML. To type a message, the user types in a `<textarea>`. To help indicate the purpose of the textarea and improve usability, there is a button that sends the message on top of the `<textarea>`. However, when the user types a longer message, the text reaches the end of the line and is partially covered up by the icon. Although there are CSS properties that control the behavior of text-wrapping, I can't find anything that would 'offset' the text wrap so that new text would go to a new line once it reached the icon. Is there a CSS property or JS workaround that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding-right` seems like the way to go. Something like this?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
textarea {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button>B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: For me, this makes the `<textarea>` have a larger width and go out of the page.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to adjust the width accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: The rows and cols attributes are just dummy values, you can adjust them to your needs as well as the padding-right property.